# android ndk: specify APP_ABI with cmake

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, ndk-build

I want to compile some `c` files for my android project. I'm using `NDK` with `cmake`. And I want to generate the `.so` files for all available CPU types. Most of the tutorials online are based on `ndk-build`, in which they specify the `APP_ABI := all` in `Application.mk` file. How can I do the same with `cmake`?
My cmake version is 3.18.1
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a "pure" CMake project, this cannot be done with a single generated build tree.

Assuming you are passing a path to a toolchain file to CMake (with `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$NDK/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake`), you should also be passing in an `ANDROID_ABI` argument. For possible values see [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake#android_abi)

You're then expected to have a separate build dir for each ABI, something like:

```
MyProjectDir/
  build_x86_64/
  build_x86/
  build_arm64/
  build_armeabi/
  src/
  ...
```

If, on the other hand, you are working with a Gradle-managed project, then the ABI is automatically controlled by Gradle and you only need to worry if you *don't* want to build for all ABIs.

Build your app as normal, and when you get an APK - open it (it's essentially a ZIP archive). Inside it should be a `lib` directory containing subdirectories for each ABI.